# Python script for converting Esri shapefile into GeoJSON using Python and GDAL/OGR?

Tags: python, shapefile, geojson, convert

I know Esri shapefile can be converted into GeoJSON using Python and GDAL/OGR. Following command works on the terminal.

```
ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -t_srs crs:84 outfile.geojson inputfile.shp
```

I want to do the conversion in a python script so that I can convert multiple files inside a loop. And combine it in my pipeline script.

Is there any way to do this conversion in python script? 
Can this terminal command be used in a python script?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Converting GeoJSON to Shapefile using ogr2ogr?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68175/converting-geojson-to-shapefile-using-ogr2ogr)

Comment: That's not in python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be used using GDAL. First, install GDAL for your OS.
You can convert files from the terminal by using following command:

```
#ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -t_srs crs:84 [output_filename].geojson [input_filename].shp
```

If you want to use python script then by calling subprocess, this can be achieved. Python script example is given below:

```py
#Convert Esri .shp file into .geoJson file

import subprocess

input_shp = 'inputfile.shp'
output_geoJson = 'outputfile.geojson'
cmd = "ogr2ogr -f GeoJSON -t_srs crs:84 "  + output_geoJson +" " + input_shp
print(cmd)
subprocess.call(cmd , shell=True)
```

Comment: No need for `subprocess`.  You can use `gdal.VectorTranslate` directly.

Comment: The help for subprocess warns against using call with shell=True, use Popen like pcs=subprocess.Popen(['ogr2ogr','-f','GeoJSON','-t_srs','crs:84',output_geoJson,input_shp]) then pcs.wait() to wait until the process finishes (optional). Beware of spaces in path names, if there is even a slim possibility of a space it's safer to use '"{}"'.format(output_geoJson) as an example to quote the element for the command processor - paths that don't have spaces but are still quoted are not a problem for the operating system.

Comment: @user2856 Thanks, gdal.VectorTranslate will be cleaner.

Comment: @MichaelStimson Thanks, I will try Popen. I wasn't aware of it. Thanks for the tips.