# Converting GeoJSON to Shapefile

Tags: python, shapefile, geojson

I have a found a lot of questions about converting shapefiles to GeoJSON, but how do you convert a GeoJSON to a Shapefile?

I've seen  [Converting GeoJSON to Shapefile using ogr2ogr?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68175) that uses `ogr2ogr`, but they look like they are commands for a shell.

Is there a pure Python script to do it?

I've also found this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44049679/geojson-to-shapefile-using-python) that runs without any errors, but the output is still a GeoJSON.

Perhaps explaining how to write as a `.shp`?

```
import geojson
import subprocess
import urllib.request as ur

url = 'http://ig3is.grid.unep.ch/istsos/wa/istsos/services/ghg/procedures/operations/geojson?epsg=3857'
response = ur.urlopen(url)
data = geojson.loads(response.read())

with open('D:/Scripts/Stand19North.geojson', 'w') as f:
    geojson.dump(data, f)

args = ['ogr2ogr', '-f', 'ESRI Shapefile', 'D:/Scripts/converted_shp.shp',
        'Stand19North.geojson']
subprocess.Popen(args)
```

Comment: It might be worth mentioning that the script: 1. downloads a GeoJSON and then 2. uses `ogr2ogr` as a subprocess. If you already have a GeoJSON file, then you may as well just run `ogr2ogr` on a shell, unless there's other work to do in Python. If this script works without raising an error, then you already have `ogr2ogr` available as a command.

Comment: @alphabetasoup yes I do have other work to do in Python. This script will be included in a batch that I am working on creating. That's why I am looking for a pure python way.

Comment: Well I used the shell and it worked. It's pure python, but I guess it will work for now.

Comment: Ogr2ogr is also available as a Python function VectorTranslate. No need to use subprocess. See the API documentation 
https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#VectorTranslate
https://gdal.org/python/osgeo.gdal-module.html#VectorTranslateOptions

Answer (score 18, accepted):

[Geopandas](https://geopandas.org/docs/user_guide/io.html) can accomplish this.

Try this:

```
import geopandas as gpd

gdf = gpd.read_file('file.geojson')
gdf.to_file('file.shp')
```

Answer (score 8):

Ogr2ogr is also available as a Python function `VectorTranslate`. No need to use subprocess. See the API documentation

https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.VectorTranslate
https://gdal.org/api/python/osgeo.gdal.html#osgeo.gdal.VectorTranslateOptions

Minimal usage example:

```
from osgeo import gdal
srcDS = gdal.OpenEx('test.json')
ds = gdal.VectorTranslate('test.shp', srcDS, format='ESRI Shapefile')
```